# How I can use python pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf in aws lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, python-3.8, pdfkit

I would like to convert html to pdf using pdfkit, but when i try to run in lambda i got the errors

```
No wkhtmltopdf executable found: ""
If this file exists please check that this process can read it or you can pass path to it manually in method call, check README. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfkit/configuration.py", line 35, in __init__
    with open(self.wkhtmltopdf) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

My code:

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_string(html_content, "testing.pdf")
```

the code is runing in my local `py` file, but not working in aws lambda. Any idea to solve this issue? or any other lib suggestions???

Thank You

Comment: Please read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html and ensure that you have packaged the depend library with code or making it available through Lambda layer so the python runtime for lambda can make it available.

Answer (score 3):

You need a add wkhtmltopdf layer to your lambda function. You can get it from here https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html#stable
And in your python code add the config to pdfkit like below

```
PATH_WKHTMLTOPDF = '/opt/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
PDFKIT_CONFIG = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=PATH_WKHTMLTOPDF)
pdfkit.from_string('somehtml',configuration=PDFKIT_CONFIG)
```